# Why is wifi disabled in nm-applet on every boot?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, 16.10, intel-wireless

I have a freshly installed Ubuntu 16.10 on a Xiaomi Air 13 notebook with intel wifi, here's some more info on the interface:

02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)

I did not activate the wifi in the installation process. Now I need to manually activate wifi in the NetworkManager applet (I'm using Mate). Once it is enabled, everything works fine. The wireless network I connect to is set to automatically connect as soon as it is in reach.

What can I do to omit the annoying step of manually activating wifi in the applet on every boot?

Update: This is the output of `rfkill list all` right after a fresh reboot:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Go to *Startup Applications > Add > Command* and write `nmcli radio wifi on`. Name it as you want and click *Add*. Reboot and come back with the outcome.

Comment: Thanks. I think that will work, but it feels like a workaround rather than going for the core problem. Maybe somebody knows where/how to change network manager's behaviour?

Comment: Please reboot and with the wireless *not* working, run: `rfkill list all` and edit your question to add the result.

Comment: Ok, Pilot6's answer seems to work, but you did the actual work ;-) If you want to answer, I'll accept yours as solution. No offense, Pilot6.

Comment: Robert, this is a very common answer. I do not think votes are important. If @chili555 really wants the points ;-) I will upvote it too. But we both have a lot already ;-) It is more important to accept. It shows others that the solution works. That is the whole point of Q&A.

Comment: @Pilot6 and I work together on many cases. Neither of us is very worried about points. We are just glad your wireless is working as expected. I upvoted his answer and I recommend that you accept it. Thanks for your respect!

Comment: Ok, that's cool :-) Just wanted to be fair. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-acer.conf <<< "blacklist acer_wmi"
```

and reboot.